# Flink Shared State and race conditions

Tags: apache-flink

Hey there I am having a hard time understanding how shared state (ValueState, ListState, ..) work in flink. If multiple instances of a task are running in parallel how does flink prevent race conditions?

in this example from the [doc](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/learn-flink/etl/#stateful-transformations), if the operator is parallelized, how does flink guarantee that there are no race conditions between the read and update of the keyHasBeenSeen value?

```
public static class Deduplicator extends RichFlatMapFunction<Event, Event> {
    ValueState<Boolean> keyHasBeenSeen;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration conf) {
        ValueStateDescriptor<Boolean> desc = new ValueStateDescriptor<>("keyHasBeenSeen", Types.BOOLEAN);
        keyHasBeenSeen = getRuntimeContext().getState(desc);
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap(Event event, Collector<Event> out) throws Exception {
        if (keyHasBeenSeen.value() == null) {
            out.collect(event);
            keyHasBeenSeen.update(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any shared state in Flink. Having shared state would add complexity and impair scalability.

The `value` and `update` methods are scoped to the key of the current event. For any given key, all events for that key are processed by the same instance of the operator/function. And all tasks (a task is a chain of operator/function instances) are single threaded.

By keeping things simple like this, there's nothing to worry about.